# How to implement constructor of declared class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to declare a class in global scope but I can't seem to be able to implement it (the constructor)

```
declare global {

    class Test {
        public readonly status: number

        constructor (status: number)
    }
}
```

I tried

```
Test.constructor = function (status: number) {
  // constructor code
}
```

and several other variations but the compiler does not like it and I can't seem to find any examples of declared classes being implemented.

How do I implement a declared class?

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, you are coming from C or C++ :) It doesn't work like this here

In typescript you don't separate type declaration and implementation. Just create a file, declare a class and implement it in place

```
export class Test {
  public foo: number = 6
  public bar: string

  constructor() {
    this.bar = "Hello world"
  }

  qux() {
    console.log(123)
  }
}
```

Then import and use it. You don't need a declaration. The purpose of declarations is to describe a type that you *do not* implement, but will exist at runtime in one way or another. Like, for example, there is a native function `parseInt`. You don't implement it, no library implements it, it's native browser's code. So you need a declaration

```
declare function parseInt(str: string, radix?: number): number
```

This doesn't create any function. This just tells the compiler "see, I don't know how this function is implemented and where it is implemented, but I know for sure at runtime it will exist, will accept 2 arguments and return a number". An example with class would be the native `RegExp` class

```
declare class RegExp {
  constructor(regexp: string | RegExp)
  
  test(str: string): boolean
  // ...
}
```

This just tells the compiler "see, the RegExp class will exist at runtime and look like this. No idea where it is implemented, but it will be there". Not that this *does not* create a `RegExp` class. If, somehow, it turns out that this class will not exist at runtime, you will get a runtime error.

Another use case is 3rd party libraries. If someone wrote a library in javascript, but they want their library to be usable in typescript, they will create a declaration file and describe all the library's function in it. Basically they say "our functions are all javascript and we don't want to rewrite their implementation in typescript. But we are sure these functions are there, they will exist at runtime and here is what they will look like".

But if you actually write the implementation in typescript, you should not use declarations.